# Get clientRect of a specific text in contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, getboundingclientrect, getclientrect

I'm trying to place a tooltip on top of a text selected via index.

```
Hello, my *name is John Doe
          ^ get the clientRect from index 10 to 14
```

Words area marked with a asterisk

I coulnd't find a way or I didnt google properly to get the clientRect of that word with specific index from/to